# Need help gaining access to the fields of a large nested SOQL query?

Tags: apex, soql, nested

Today I am using a nested query for the first time.I have a giant query and I am having trouble using it in the best way.

After a couple of days of using this style
`for (variable : list_or_set)` of for loop I believe I need to change to the more traditional loop 
`for (init_stmt; exit_condition; increment_stmt)`

During each loop I have to build many different Objects. This query is way larger than what I have here as example. What is the best way to access these fields?

**Scenario:**

For instance on the first loop I need to make the first Location the Main Location and the rest of them Add Locations. Using the first style of for loop I mentioned I was having trouble getting that first Location.

```
for(LocationTable loc: location)  
{   
   business = loc.business__r;  
   store  = loc.store__r;  
   doc = loc.documents__r;  
   bank= loc.banks__r;  
// DO STUFF 
// THIS IS HOW I'VE BEEN ACCESSING THE FIELDS BUT SEEMS LIKE THERE IS A BETTER WAY   
}



List<BankTable> bank = new List<BankTable>();

List<StoreTable> store = new List<StoreTable>();

List<BusinessDocumentsTable> doc = new List<BusinessDocumentsTable>();

List<BusinessTable> business = new List<BusinessTable>();

List<LocationTable> location = new List<LocationTable>();

List<ApplicationTable> app = new List<ApplicationTable>();


location = 
[
    SELECT             
        Name,
        Application,
        (
            SELECT 
                Name, 
                Address,
                City, 
                Contact_First_Name,
                Contact_Last_Name,
                Email, 
                Fax, 
                Phone, 
                State, 
                LocationLookup, 
                Zip_Code__c
            FROM 
                StoreTable  
        ),
        (
            SELECT
                Name, 
                AccountNumber, 
                BankCity, 
                BankName, 
                BankPhone, 
                BankState, 
                RoutingNumber, 
                Routing_Number__c,
                LocationLookup
            FROM 
                BankTable
        ),
        (
            SELECT
                Name,
                PaymentType, 
                FaceToFacePercentage,
                MOTOPercentage ,
                InternetPercentage, 
                FNS_Number__c, 
                LocationLookup
            FROM
                BusinessTable
        ),
        (
            SELECT
                Key,
                Bucket,
                ContentType,
                DocType,
                Description,
                File_Name,
                ShortFileName
                LocationLookup
            FROM
                BusinessDocumentsTable
        )
    FROM
        LocationTable
    WHERE
        ApplicationTable = '123456789'
];
```

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? I am not sure I understand what is wrong. Also, neither your objects nor your fields have `__c` added to them, you may want to check it

Comment: I did not want to put down exact fields when I wrote this so I made up a fake query that is identical. I am a junior developer and did want my work stuff on here. My question is what are the ways to access these fields in a nested query like this. My query works but I feel like I am not getting full use of the query the way I am trying to access it now. My bad if this doesnt make sense.

Comment: what do you want to do with the children stores, documents, etc? The SOQL query will return a big datastructure that can be processed with for loops (of each child) within for loops (of Location).  The general solution is the same for one child relationship as it is for n child relationships so you can edit your post and eliminate the stores, docs, and banks

Comment: @twiggler I tried to rephrase your question and answer the same. Please confirm whether thats what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

I will make the question clear since it took some time for me to understand it too.

```
// Pseudocode 

// Input
locations = [1,2,3,4,5]

// Output
MainLocation = 1
AddLocations = [2,3,4,5]
```

So here:

```
List<Location> locations = [Select Id From Location];
```

You want to set the first element in this List as `MainLocation` and rest as `AddLocations` as below.

```
Location MainLocation = locations.get(0);
List<Location> AddLocations = locations.remove(0);
```

**Options of Iterating through collections:**

Here locations is a collection and Apex supports the following five types of procedural loops:

- `do {statement} while (Boolean_condition);`
- `while (Boolean_condition) statement;`
- `for (initialization; Boolean_exit_condition; increment) statement;`
- `for (variable : array_or_set) statement;`
- `for (variable : [inline_soql_query]) statement;`

**Solution:**

We don't want to use `while` or `do while` so I can think of two ways to do this

- **Using `for (initialization; Boolean_exit_condition; increment) statement;`** as you mentioned

  ```
   Location MainLocation;
   List<Location> AddLocations = new List<Location>();
   for(integer i=0; i<locations.size(); i++) {
      if(i==0)
         MainLocation = locations[i];
      else
         AddLocations.add(locations[i]);
   }
  ```
- **Using `for (variable : array_or_set) statement;`**

  ```
   Location MainLocation;
   List<Location> AddLocations = new List<Location>();
   integer count = 0;

   for(Location loc: locations) {
      if(count==0)
         MainLocation = loc;
      else
         AddLocations.add(loc);
      count++;
   }
  ```

**Limitations:**

> Apex currently doesn't have [List.indexOf(element)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops.htm) as well as [for with index](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops.htm) looping structures so these are the only possible ways to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a technique that I have used for years that someone shared with me here on SF.SE several years ago. Sadly, I can't recall who it was and don't have the time at the moment to search back to find the post, but can only say it has been extremely helpful.

When I have queries of the type you have, I always return them as Maps. This makes retrieving what you need MUCH easier. This method allows you to retrieve everything you want as lists quite easily. Be sure to remember to use the plural of any standard objects in your queries (eg: Contact becomes Contacts). Here's an example of the technique to use as a guide:

```
    Map<Id, Account> AcctOppCustomObjectMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id
                                                                ,(SELECT xxx 
                                                                    FROM xxx__r)
                                                                ,(SELECT yyy 
                                                                    FROM yyy__r) 
                                                            FROM Account
                                                            WHERE Id IN :idSet]);

    List<yyy__c> yyyThings = new List<yyy__c>();
    List<xxx__c> xxxxThings = new List<xxx__c>();

    for (Id accountId : AcctOppCustomObjectMap.keyset()) {
        Account acct = AcctOppCustomObjectMap.get(accountId);

        // the acct reference will have child or related lists for your subqueries
        // they will not be null, but they could be empty lists
        List<xxx__c> xxxList = acct.xxx__r;
        List<yyy__c> yyyList = acct.yyy__r;

        // iteration of the child or related records is now possible using these two lists
        for (xxx__c xThing : xxxList) {

           // if there's filtering I need to do or other work on the list, 
           // I can do it in a loop like below
           if(xThing.isEmpty() == false){ 

              if(xThing.xxx == yThing.yyy) xThing.zzz = acct.Id

              xxxThings.add(xThing);
           }
        }

        for (yyy__c yThing : yyyList) {

           // the same thing can be done for the other objects or both

           if(yThing.yyy == xThing.xxx) yyyThings.add(yThing);
        }
    }

    // I now have list xxxThings and list yyyThings pulled from the Map and sorted as needed
```